# return only source data from elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I post a query to elasticsearch get data of index.. I only need these fields data and how many documents found information... but there is "took","shards" and inside of a document "_id","_index","_score". these are un necessary for my purpose..

Here my simple request:

```
query='{"query": {"match_all": {}}}';
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:9200/webproxylog/_search?source=" + query,
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $.param(params),
        success: function(data) {...
```

I check the response data in success method here how it seems:
[image]

I just want to get hits which documents in, and in documents I just want to "_source" object that have fields data."took","shards","_id","_index", unneccessary, how can I disable them

Comment: Why do you not using ElasticJs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html ?

Comment: because I didnt know such a library exist :D interesting.. then you mean its easy with e.sj to get only content, I dont want parse with response.hits.hits (in documents you share)I just want elasticsearch return exactly what I need.

Comment: You will save a lot of time doing another things than just parsing the returned JSON yourself ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't turn off the response meta-data. You can return [`fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) instead of `_source` if you only want specific fields, but that doesn't really decrease the complexity. The library can abstract some of that away, but I don't find it terribly difficult to simply parse the ES responses directly.

You do, of course, have to write a little JavaScript. Luckily it's not too hard. Something like this usually works nicely for me:

```
var results = es_response_data['hits']['hits'].map(function(i){
    return i['_source']; 
});
```

Comment: Yes that's idea sounds good to me. thank you in the other hand I am not awere of difficulty of parse it,  these unnecessary data would be post to client and consume bandwidth and slow performance a little.. I just wonder it is possible or not  turn off that:)

Answer (score 32):

Yes you can remove the extra fields from _source

Answer is just one simple word **`filter_path`**

**Curl :**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/webproxylog/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source'
```

**Node :**

If you are using any node '`elasticsearch`' you need to add just one extrs param `filterPath`

```
client.search({
        index: 'index',
        type: 'type',
        filterPath : ['hits.hits._source'], // this will remove extra fileds _index / _score / _id ...
        body: {
            sort: [
                {"posted_dt": {"order": "desc"}},
                "_score"
            ],
            query: query,
            size: 50,
            from: index * 50
        }
    }
```

**In your case :**

you just need to add that extra field in your url like:

```
"http://localhost:9200/webproxylog/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source&source=" + query
```

Comment: for anyone coming here and looking for a solution in python: using elasticsearch official client for python filter path is an argument you can pass in the search method of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [ElasticJS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html), the API recommended by ElasticSearch will help JS client to communicate easily with elasticsearch nodes. You will save a lot of time by using this API.

Comment: I got your point, if I were begining I could use this, but I just need 2-3 type of only search, so cant add external library to project at this time. But its useful knowledge thank you.